# Access Register physical address from User Space

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm new in Linux world, and would like to ask a question for this forum:

If I want to access physical address from user space, and I don't have any Kernel driver implementation for this specific hardware device - Can I do it?

I know this is not the "right" way to do so, just want to know if there is a way.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Why do you ask? Unless you are coding a driver, or something accessing a graphical card, you should not care!

Comment: This is a General question, for learning purposes

Comment: Coming from an embedded environment where I have direct access to pins and registers, I am able to toggle pins by directly accessing sram registers in various micro's I have used.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot in general access physical addresses (from user-space program) on Linux.

However, you might perhaps want to [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) the `/dev/mem` device (see [mem(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) for details).

You'll still use [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) with virtual addresses, but you'll happen to see part of the physical RAM.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible to access an arbitrary physical address from application without a system call. (That means you need an existing driver or you need to write a kernel space driver to do map required register for you)

Mmap also work on virtual address. So if your physical addresses maps to a logical address then only you can get a mapping of the wanted physical address and access it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your hardware architecture you might not be able to directly access the address of a register because of the memory protection mechanics and because memory addresses "seen" by the kernel are different from the one seen from a user space process.
You will need some kernel space code that will map back and forth the register address to a memory address that makes sense for your user speca process. Try reading about memory mapping and mmap () related syscalls